# how to pass an array value as an object key, and associate that key with some values in the object. and then pass it into a list item

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass an array values as keys of an object and in that object there are two values for each key, and then I want to pass it into a list item. how I can do that.
this what i have tried so far:

```js
'use strict';

const bookTitles = [
  'harry_potter_chamber_secrets',
  'small_island',
  'spook_street',
  'war_and_peace',
  'don_quixote',
  'a_tale_of_two_cities',
  'the_lord_of_the_rings',
  'harry_potter_and_the_secret_stone',
  'and_then_there_were_none',
  'the_hobbit',
];

console.log(bookTitles);

function booksInfoF(array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){


    var booksInfoTrial = { array[i]: [{ author: 'somebody', language: 'english'}]}
  }

  return booksInfoTrial;

}

var outPut;
 outPut.booksInfoF(bookTitles);

listNode = document.createElement('ul');
liNode = document.createElement('LI');
textNode = document.createTextNode(outPut);

liNode.appendChild(textNode);
listNode.appendChild(liNode);
```

Comment: Expected result?

Comment: You can push `booksInfoTrial` to an array inside `for` loop and return the array form the function. But *"Lord of the Rings"* and *"Harry Potter"* will have the same `author` named "*somebody*"

Comment: You have to declare `var booksInfoTrial`outside of the for loop. Otherwise it will be recreated every loop. What should the return value of booksInfoF should look like ?

Comment: the expected result should be a list of books associated with their language and authors. for instance : harry_potter_chamber_secrets  , english, J.K Rolling

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution.

```js
var obj = [
  'harry_potter_chamber_secrets',
  'small_island',
  'spook_street',
  'war_and_peace',
  'don_quixote',
  'a_tale_of_two_cities',
  'the_lord_of_the_rings',
  'harry_potter_and_the_secret_stone',
  'and_then_there_were_none',
  'the_hobbit',
].reduce((ac, cv, i) => Object.assign(ac, {[cv] : [{author: 'somebody', language: 'english'}]}), {});

console.log(obj);
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: it looks excellent, It worked with console.log but when I try to append it into a list item nothing shows.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<ul id="myList">
</ul>

<p>Click the button to append an item to the end of the list.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>

var books = [
  'harry_potter_chamber_secrets',
  'small_island',
  'spook_street',
  'war_and_peace',
  'don_quixote',
  'a_tale_of_two_cities',
  'the_lord_of_the_rings',
  'harry_potter_and_the_secret_stone',
  'and_then_there_were_none',
  'the_hobbit',
].reduce((ac, cv, i) => Object.assign(ac, {[cv] : {author: 'somebody', language: 'english'}}), {});

function myFunction() {
  var UL = document.createElement("UL");
  
  for(bookname in books){
 var book_name = bookname.split('_').join(' ').toUpperCase();
    var book = books[bookname];
 var LI = document.createElement("LI");
 var TX = document.createTextNode(book_name);
 LI.appendChild(TX);
 
    UL.appendChild(TX); 
    
    var _UL = document.createElement("UL");
  
    var I1 = document.createElement("LI");
 var t1 = document.createTextNode('author: '+book.author);
    I1.appendChild(t1);
 
    var I2 = document.createElement("LI");
    var t2 = document.createTextNode('language: '+book.language);
    I2.appendChild(t2);

    _UL.appendChild(I1);
    _UL.appendChild(I2);
   
   UL.appendChild(document.createElement("LI").appendChild(_UL));

  }
 
  document.getElementById("myList").appendChild(UL); 
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot. this is a good way to do it. appreciate you help.